# Gloabl.asax Context.RewritePath IIS 7.5

Tags: url-rewriting, global-asax

The following code-snippet works fine when I run it in debug mode, but throws a 404 when I run it through IIS (7.5)

Is there a web.config setting I need to add for IIS?

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currentUrl = Request.Url.ToString();
        List<string> pages = new List<string>();
        pages.Add("/about-us.html");
        pages.Add("/services");

        foreach (string page in pages )
        {
            if (currentUrl.Contains(page))
            {
                Context.RewritePath(string.Format("/page.aspx?page={0}", page));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you are trying to do this yourself instead of using the built in support for IIS 7.5 or something like the Managed Fusion Url Rewriter http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` in `<system.WebServer>` in Web.config.

Comment: Thanks, worked great. For simple sites, I think the Context.RewritePath concept is OK, when would you recommend system.web.routing over this method?

Comment: I have this in my web.config file already but am still having issues with IIS 7.5 and Context.RewritePath. Any other suggestions?